# Delete Kubernetes PVC ebs volumes in batch

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I have more than 4000 pvc in my kubernetes aws eks cluster.

- From those 4000+ pvc I have to delete almost 3999 pvcs

Now instead of using command:

```
kubetcl delete pvc pvc-data-name
```

and delete every pvc separately which can take me sooo long.. I want to find a way to delete them in batches or all together.

Comment: `kubectl delete pvc --field-selector metadata.name!=<name_to_ignore>`. you can test with `kubectl get` before changing to `kubectl delete`.

Comment: i personally tried python kubernetes client and it worked like 10 times faster than kubectl when deleting tons of objects

Comment: @VasiliAngapov and how did u do that?

Comment: @jordanm thanks.. I will try it out! However, just to clarify: I dont have to delete like 30 pvc so in the "metadata.name!=<name-to_ignore>" that u have in the command do I add the names of all those 30?

Comment: @jordanm for example.. like if I have 5 pvc data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 ... how do add all infront of the "metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete>"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this one.

```
kubectl delete pvc --field-selector metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete-1>, metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete-2>, metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete-3>
```

or,
also you can do this with `go-client`. to do this with go client see the document [Ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)

i have added a label in every `pvc` that i don't want to delete.

```
  labels:
    test: test-1
```

```
import (
   "context"
   "fmt"
   metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"

   "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
   "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
   "kmodules.xyz/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
   "log"
   "path/filepath"
)

func testFunc() ( error) {
   masterURL := ""

   kubeconfigPath := filepath.Join(homedir.HomeDir(), ".kube", "config")



   config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags(masterURL, kubeconfigPath)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("Could not get Kubernetes config: %s", err)
   }

   kc := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(config)
   labelSelector := &metav1.LabelSelector{
       MatchExpressions: []metav1.LabelSelectorRequirement{
           {
               "test",
               metav1.LabelSelectorOpNotIn,
               []string{
                   "test-0",
                   "test-1",
               },
           },
       },
   }
   err = kc.CoreV1().PersistentVolumeClaims("default").DeleteCollection(context.TODO(), metav1.DeleteOptions{}, metav1.ListOptions{
       LabelSelector: metav1.FormatLabelSelector(labelSelector),
   })
   fmt.Println(err)
   
   return  nil
}
```

Comment: Emon thank you.. I will try it out! However, just to clarify: I dont have to delete like around 30 pvc so in the "metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete>" that u have in the command do I add the names of all those 30?

Comment: Emon for example, like if I have 5 pvc data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 ... how do add all infront of the "metadata.name!=<name-dont-want-to-delete>"??

Comment: @Myra For keeping multiple pvc you better try the second one.

Comment: @Myra i have updated my  ans . can you try the `kubectl` one?

Comment: Emon sure.. but i am facing another problem..when typing the command on my terminal (it has like 40 pvc that I dont want to delete) it is not pasting the full command? how do I fix that

Comment: i haven't get it. can you explain a little more?

Comment: Emon pls see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988112/mac-terminal-command-input-too-long-it-does-not-fit

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with grep and xargs

```
kubectl get pvc | grep -v <name-to-not-include> | xargs kubectl delete pvc --grace-period=0 --force
```

Update:

For multiple patterns:

```
kubectl get pvc | grep -v 'pattern1\|pattern2' | xargs kubectl delete pvc --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: I want to include more than one pvc to "<name-to-not-include>".. how do I do that?

Comment: for multiple patterns 'pattern1\|pattern2', dont forget to scape the | with \