# Mac terminal command input too long it does not fit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, kubernetes, terminal, kubectl

I need to run the command:

```
kubectl get pvc --field-selector metadata.name!=dataX********************************,******************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,dataY***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,***************************************************,*********************************************,****************************************************,*******************************************,******************************************************,*****************************************,*******************************************************,****************************************,********************************************************,***************************************,*********************************************************,**************************************,**********************************************************,*************************************,***********************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,***********************************,*************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,*************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,***********************************,*************************************************************,************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,**********************************************************,**************************************,***********************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,***********************************,***********************************************************,************************************,*********************************************************,**************************************,********************************************************,***************************************,*******************************************************,***************************************,*******************************************************,*************************************,***********************************dataZ
```

however when I paste it in the mac terminal to run.. it only pastes till:

```
kubectl get pvc --field-selector metadata.name!=dataX********************************,******************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,dataY***********************************************,
```

I have hidden the actual data values.. but take the dataX dataY and dataX as examples...

- whole command has total 536
- it only pastes 185
- now how do I fit all the terminal?

Comment: @H.R Emon pls see I edited question to add numbers

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with script:

Write the command in a script file. like: `test.sh`.

And may be you need to add `x` mod also, to make it executable.
just run the command to change the mod.

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

steps will be like this :

1. `nano test.sh`.
2. add the command inside the script.
3. `chmod +x test.sh`.
4. run `./test.sh`

**test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

kubectl get pvc --field-selector metadata.name!=dataX********************************,******************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,************************************************,************************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,*************************************************,dataY***********************************************,*************************************************,***********************************************,***************************************************,*********************************************,****************************************************,*******************************************,******************************************************,*****************************************,*******************************************************,****************************************,********************************************************,***************************************,*********************************************************,**************************************,**********************************************************,*************************************,***********************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,***********************************,*************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,*************************************************************,***********************************,************************************************************,***********************************,*************************************************************,************************************,***********************************************************,*************************************,**********************************************************,**************************************,***********************************************************,************************************,************************************************************,***********************************,***********************************************************,************************************,*********************************************************,**************************************,********************************************************,***************************************,*******************************************************,***************************************,*******************************************************,*************************************,***********************************dataZ
```

then run  `./test.sh` in `CLI`.

Comment: Emon how do I create the test.sh? by "nano test.sh"?

Comment: Emon when do I need to run the chmod +x test.sh? .. before "./test.sh"? or after?

Comment: i have updated my ans with the steps. can you take a look again please. @Myra

Comment: Emon as I am in the kubernetes cluster.. in its terminal.. I cannot run those I am getting errors: 
sh: ./ebs-test.sh: not found
chmod: ebs-test.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: can you specify in which command you are stuck ?

Comment: when I run: ./ebs-test.sh in the kuberntetes shell I have connected to & when I run chmod +x ebs-test.sh

Comment: `No such file or directory ` that means you need to define the path correctly

Comment: first go into the directory where you have saved the `ebs-test.sh` file